# Работа с множеством событий от объектов одного типа

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть некоторая коллекция объектов одного типа и хотел бы получать события от каждого объекта.

Правильно ли будет создать статическое событие в этом типе или лучше пройтись по всем объектам и подписаться на каждое событие?

Comment: вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2789642/5796587) есть немного рассуждений на тему. Если кратко - со статическими событиями нужно особенно следить за своевременной отпиской от них, т.к. они будут держать ссылку до выгрузки класса, что может привести к утечкам памяти, если забывать от них отписываться.

Comment: везде где только можно рекомендуют избегать статики и синглтона.

Comment: Нет, конечно. Если вы хотите получать события от каждого объекта, то вы и _должны получать события от каждого объекта_. В программировании практика «вижу, что статическое, думаю, что от объекта» порочна, и приводит к багам. Не запутывайте себя сами, программирование — сложная штука и без этого.